# Import library in Eclipse without jar

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, gradle, repository

I'm using Eclipse for developing an Android application. I need to use a library that can be imported using gradle (from Maven repository), since the jar is not provided. How can I do this?

Comment: Your question is misleading! You are using Eclipse but want to import that library using Gradle? FYI, Eclipse doesn't support Gradle build system!

Comment: I know. So, is there a way for use [this library](https://github.com/shell-software/fab) in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

Have you try [this](http://codetutr.com/2013/03/23/how-to-import-gradle-project-into-eclipse/) link?

Create a new folder called basic-eclipse.

Inside the folder, create folders src/main/java.

Create the Gradle build file in the basic-eclipse folder with the following contents:

```
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    targetCompatibility = 1.6

    dependencies {
        compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:20030203.000129'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.+'
    }
```

From the command line, run gradle eclipse

Now, go into Eclipse and choose File -> Import -> Existing Projects into Workspace and choose the basic-eclipse folder that you created.

import-eclipse-project Notice that src/main/java is automatically configured to be the source directory. Also, the Commons-Lang and Junit jars have been downloaded and added to our build path automatically (in addition to Hamcrest, a jar that Junit depends on).

Comment: Thank you. But should this help me for importing, into Eclipse, a library in `.aar` format?

Comment: In that case, you should take an action. I think that will take 15 minute to try. So if it succeds, saves a hour or more :).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Android Development Toolkit (ADT) does not yet support AAR dependencies.

Please see here for more information:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=59183

There is an open ticket for the [Android for Maven Eclipse](http://rgladwell.github.io/m2e-android/) project to bring AAR support to Eclipse:

https://github.com/rgladwell/m2e-android/issues/177

Also, the Andmore project is looking to bring AAR support to Eclipse:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=459569

Answer (score -1):

According to your questions,you want to import '.jar' and '.aar',I think you should chose AS.

Comment: I can't chose. It is a collaborative project, that already exists in Eclipse enviroment.